# How can I convert WAV to Apple lossless in the terminal?

Tags: macos, audio

I have a lot of WAV files that I do not wish to import into iTunes to convert.  There are too many.  I would like a way to convert these to Apple lossless in the terminal before importing to iTunes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to make a short bash for loop in a script (or `xargs`) but the command in question you care about is:

`afconvert -d alac in.wav out.m4a`

More info can be found by running `man afconvert` or `afconvert -h`.

Comment: Simple one line loop example: 
`for file in *.wav; do afconvert -d alac "$file" "${file%wav}m4a"; done`

Comment: `afconvert` has a pretty limited range of input formats, I'd suggest using `ffmpeg` which has the builtin alac encoder too but supports tons of audio formats and it also tries to keep the metadata from the source as much as possible. e.g.  `ffmpeg -i input.whatever -vn -c:a alac -f ipod output.m4a`

Comment: @meow `ffmpeg` solution is worth a competing top-level answer to the question, IMO.